# Core Data - NSManagedObjectContext vs NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

According to apple documentation of [`NSFetchedResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFetchedResultsController):

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results
>   returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a
>   UITableView object.

According to documentation of [`NSManagedObjectContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html):

> Its primary responsibility is to manage a collection of managed
>   objects.

It seems that purpose of these two classes overlap. Both "manage the fetched managed objects". Maybe the difference of wording indeed mean something, yet I don't get it. After reading both docs, it seems to me that all the data fetch, modify, commit, undo/redo etc. is handled by the managed context. I don't see the point of nsfrc existing.

Could anyone explain why do we need fetched results controller when we already have managed context to deal with data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NSManagedObjectContext` is a fundamental concept of Core Data, kind of analagous to a transaction in a relational data. Not only can you fetch objects, you can create, update and delete them, save them back to the persistent store, etc.

You don't *need* the `NSFetchedResultsController`. It's a utility class, one designed to provide Core Data objects in a format that's easily usable in a table view. The fetched objects used in an `NSFetchedResultsController` will be managed by an `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Having said that, "utility class" seriously undersells it. It automatically manages things like updates, inserts and deletes in the underlying data source, caching, sections, etc., things that are a pain to deal with manually.

Comment: So MOC use a fetch request A to get some data from persistent store. Then FRC use fetch request B to get data from that MOC to feed a table view controller. A and B are two different fetch request. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

A `NSFetchedResultsController` has a reference to a `NSManagedObjectContext` .

The FRC has a responsibility to fetch and sort all objects from its MOC according to the criteria that you give it.

The FRC is a utility class for working with objects from a given MOC.

e.g  `All People with firstName is 'John', sorted by lastName`

Should you add a new person with `firstName = 'John'` to the MOC referenced by the FRC, the fetched results controller will work it out and send out a delegate callback.

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    //do some stuff 
}
```

The `NSManagedObjectContext` is a bucket of things. The `NSFetchedResultsController` is one way of picking particular things from that bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The fetched results controller merely fetches a set and monitors it for changes so that a table view can be updated automatically.  You don't actually make any changes to the `NSFetchedResultsController` directly.  It is linked to a context (in which you DO make changes) and result set.

Comment: Could you specify each "it" refers to what exactly? I don't get you.

Comment: it = NSFetchedResultsController